# How can an Administrator change Mac & Window users' LAN login passwords?

Tags: windows, password, local-area-network, mac

As an administrator managing Mac and Windows Users, via a web application, how can I change/reset a user’s LAN password to allow them to login to their Macs and Windows?

I am looking for an example of a web application, preferably ASP.NET but any other web language will do, that lets an administrator change Mac and Windows LAN password.

Any technique, application, or source code will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "LAN password"?  Do you mean just a user password used to log on to their workstations?  Is this authentication done through a Active Directory domain, through LDAP, through another directory system, or just with local users?

Answer (score 2):

I assume LAN password is Active Directory password? The below is self-service which I think can be better than an admin needing to intervene. I haven't really seen solutions for an admin to login and reset other people's passwords. We just have the admins run Active Directory Users and Computers to reset other people's passwords...

http://www.netwrix.com/web-based_password_reset_for_active_directory_freeware.html